# D-class audio amplifier like MAX98357A output for headset

Tags: audio, headphones, class-d

The [MAX98357A/MAX98357B PCM Input Class D Audio Power Amplifiers](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3006/MAX98357A-MAX98357B.pdf) as used in [Adafruit I2S 3W Class D Amplifier Breakout - MAX98357A](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3006) specify 4 or 8 Ohm speaker resistance, with 33 or 68 uH inductance.

I want to use it (or some other breakout board with digital input, but I have found none) for my Plattan 2 (bluetooth) headset, which has a resistance of 50 Ohm per channel. I need mono, and at 25 Ohm then I wonder what the typical uH would be? Would I need to add a coil in parallel with the output, and with which value?

I am asking because I assume it would be rather low resistance value in such an inductance (like [DR221-513AE - Ferritt, SMD SMD, 1.4kOhm @ 150MHz, Bourns](https://www.elfadistrelec.no/no/ferritt-smd-smd-4kohm-150mhz-bourns-dr221-513ae/p/30238905?queryFromSuggest=true)) which has a resistance of some 320 mOhm only. This could jeopardise the whole idea of using that board.

Ok or any better idea?

Øyvind Teig, Trondheim, Norway

Comment: Using class D to produce a few hundred mW for headphones seems, overkill and not likely to be energy beneficial.

Comment: You don't need a parallel coil, but I would implement board space for two ferrite beads and two small filter capacitors, just in case you get EMI problems with a longer headphone cable.

Comment: Thank you. I just want something simple to get into my box, it's just for monitoring an input that I sample, before the data is going into my DSP stuff. The board from Adafruit seems to have ferrite beads in the two lines and two caps of 220 pF each